# Why are there different results with these two ways to get the boolean?

Tags: java, jvm, unsafe

I wrote the codes:

```
public class StaticBooleanDemo {
  private static boolean flag;

  public static boolean getFlag(){
    return flag;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args ) throws Exception{
    Unsafe unsafe = MyJVMUtil.getUnsafe();
    Field field = StaticBooleanDemo.class.getDeclaredField("flag");
    unsafe.putInt(StaticBooleanDemo.class,
    unsafe.staticFieldOffset(field),2);
    System.out.println("getFlag():"+getFlag());
    System.out.println("flag:"+flag);

  } 

}
```

```
public class MyJVMUtil {
   public static Unsafe getUnsafe(){
    try {
        Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) field.get(null);
        return unsafe;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I got two results,the first is false,the second is true. I’m puzzled,and wonder why are there two different results for the variable flag?
But when I run it in two IDE, it also give different results,the first is in eclipse,and the second is in idea.
[eclispe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0yyn.jpg)
[idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXmFV.jpg)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208303/discussion-on-question-by-blackorwhiteface-why-are-there-different-results-with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you’re using unsafe, which as the name suggests isn’t a safe thing to do - so when you see issues like this you shouldn’t rely on that behaviour.

What you are probably seeing is a difference in either the compiler or the JVM between the two IDEs. You are writing an Int value (which is 4 bytes) and even that only works because it is being run on a little endian machine, because the first byte is where the non-zero value is. You may be trashing the next value on the heap by doing this.

Given that the representation of the boolean isn’t strictly tied down by the language, it may be that one compiler is generating bytecode for “is it zero” and the other is looking at the low order bit to depend on if it is set; i.e. the difference between `x != 0` and `x & 1` which could give the behaviour you describe.

I recommend using `javap` to see what the generated bytecode looks like in the first instance, then check that you are running them in the same JVM secondly.

But the final recommendation is not to use Unsafe at all, and especially don’t overwrite data on the heap by writing more than the field will take.